# Is there a way to call application:set_env in an eunit test?

Tags: erlang, eunit

Is it possible in an eunit test to set an environment variable used in the code under test? This fails with `**error:undef`:

```
example_test() ->
  application:set_env(an_app, example_key, "value").
```

Edit:

There's not much to show for the error, but here's the full stack:

```
    env_request_handler_tests: a_test_ (example_test)...*failed*
in function application:set_env/3
  called as set_env(an_app,example_key,"value")
in call from env_request_handler_tests:'-a_test_/0-fun-2-'/1 (include/test_fixture.hrl, line 13)
**error:undef
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Perhaps you can provide more details about the error?

Comment: @SteveVinoski. Added some more. That's all there is, really. Not much to go on.

Comment: If you take the code you show, put it in a module, compile it and run it under `eunit:test` it works fine. I also added it to an existing test module of one my projects, and it worked fine there too. So the error is elsewhere; if possible, please post more details of the code in which the error occurs.

Comment: It turned out to be that 'application' was mecked out without using passthrough. :( Now it works fine. D'oh.